# Why does my sql statment return the same output multiple times

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

Hell everyone.

I made a sql statment that returns me the name of a teacher, the time he has to attend the class and what type of class he is giving. My statement returns what i expect but it returns the same answer multiple time, why is that ? I don't quite undersand it.

Here is my statement

```
SELECT
`profile`.`name`,
`profile`.nachname,
unterichts_zeit.zeit,
unterichts_typ.typ
FROM
unterichts_zeit
INNER JOIN `profile` ON unterichts_zeit.lehrer = `profile`.id ,
unterichts_typ
```

And my output

```
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    klavier
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   klavier
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    gittare
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   gittare
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    generell
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   generell
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    schlagzeug
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   schlagzeug
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    trombone
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   trombone
teacher1    teacher1    9:35    generell
teacher2    teacher2    10:35   generell
```

Seeing this now it also doesnt really display what i want ... 
it display every type of class which is not correct obv... damn

if anyone has an idea how i can solve this

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mixed your join styles and created a Cartesian product. A Cartesian product is where the number of rows grows because unrelated rows are joined together. Sometimes it is useful, but usually it is not what is required

At the very end of your sql statement you have a comma and then another table name

The database has taken the work it already did with the INNER JOINed pair of tables and then just combined every row from them with every row from this table

If you intend to join 3 tables together use another inner join statement

```
SELECT
`profile`.`name`,
`profile`.nachname,
unterichts_zeit.zeit,
unterichts_typ.typ
FROM
unterichts_zeit
INNER JOIN `profile` ON unterichts_zeit.lehrer = `profile`.id
INNER JOIN unterichts_typ ON <<fill-this-on-clause-out>>
```

In the old days we joined tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b, c
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.id = c.id
```

If you left off the WHERE clause the db would just output every row combination. If A contained 1 and 2 and B contained "x" and "y" and c contained true and false you'd get:

```
1,x,true
1,x,false
1,y,true
1,y,false
2,x,true
2,x,false
2,y,true
2,y,false
```

Now the modern equivalent is to use INNER JOIN, and it's a lot harder to forget the ON clause (equivalent of the old way using the where clause) because it's a syntax error to do so. But db still allow the old way too and even allow mixing. Your statement having "comma tablename" at the end is a mixed join style, old way of producing a Cartesian product (forgotten where clause)

Comment: Im struggling a bit on the on clause, do you need any other table to help me out a bit more ?

Comment: The ON clause is where you declare which column in each table holds the same values as the the other table. If you had an Order table and a Product table, the order holding the list of product a customer wanted on their order then you might reasonably say `ON orders.productid = products.id` - this means "the productid column in the orders table has the same value as the id column in the products table" - tell the db how the data in unterichts_typ relates to the data in the rest of the query so it can complete the join

Comment: Got it, like this ```unterichts_typ.id = `profile`.id ```

Comment: Like that, yes. Usually I would expect columns to be helpfully named; the main I’d column of a table is usually ID or TablenameID. Columns in other tables that relate to this column are typically called TabkenameId. When designing a db I try I keep to that convention and if there are multiple columns that link to the same table I retry to give the reason. Imagine you had an Employee table and an Address table, and you wanted to record an employee home and work address. Address would have ID and address details. employee table would have Work_AddressID and Home_AddressID.

Comment: One employee record would relate to two address recordS. queries that wanted both details would join the addresses tank in twice - handy thing to remember - no one ever said you were limited to joining a table once. It is perfectly legal to say `from table employee e join address home on e.home_addressid=home.id join address work on e.work_addressid=work.id ` - here we join the Address table twice aliasing  one as work and one as home